# Getting HTML doc to display updated information

Tags: javascript, html

I made a simple HTML application which is utilized on about 12 different machines in a LAN. I saved the documents in a shared hard drive thinking that would be good enough to get all the applications to update simultaneously whenever I made changes to the HTML. I made a shortcut to the main document on everyone's computer, and from there they can navigate to the other pages on the application. I recently made changes to one of the HTML docs, and saved it to the share drive, however when I use the shortcut icon on the desktop, it displayed the HTML the way it was before I made changes. I was able to fix this by deleting the shortcut icon, and replacing it with a new one, but this is going to be a colossal pain in the butt if I have to do that to every machine whenever I make small changes to the application. I know this is a rudimentary way of operating, I'm new to this.

What would be the best way to get everything to update on everyone's machine, and display the changes without having to replace the shortcut icon every time? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One way would be to use an actual web server instead of a file system...

Comment: You change content on your .html file or you changed the name of the file ? If just changed content, it's probably a cache problem on the user browser, but it's hard to force browser to reload the page. Can you try same thing and just SHIFT+F5 to refresh browser ? to make sure this is the issue

Comment: Thanks Mike! That would be ideal, however, it isn't my system and I have limited permissions. Where I work, we have a lot of documents scattered across the shared drive. So I took it upon myself to bring all of our common forms and web applications we use under one, easy to use page written in HTML.

Comment: @ Pierre Granger, changed content on .html. Using the original shortcut icon displays the .html file before I made changes to it. So far the only way to get it display the new content is to replace the shortcut icon.

Comment: So caveat question, does the shortcut file update with the parent document, or is it a separate file which needs to be update manually? I thought the shortcut file on the desktop would mirror whatever changes are made to the file it is linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling cache might works.

Not sure what all below line does.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1900 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Explanation & Reference:http://securityevaluators.com/knowledge/case_studies/caching/